# Why do the leaves on my Lady of White Collar fig tree have brown edges to them?

Tags: leaves, fruit-trees, watering, figs

I have planted a Lady of White Collar fig tree in a hot, arid climate in a very windy spot.  The tree was planted as a sapling in Jan 2022.

It has been watered well, but its look like something is wrong with it - all the leaves have brown edges.
[image: Tree in garden]

Perhaps it's not been watered very well - the soil it's in appears to loose, but I am aware the 1 metre down, there is a hard layer.
It has 2 Gardena watering heads (Adjustable Endline Drip Head, pressure equalizing) to water it once per day, 20 minutes each time, meaning it is getting 5.3 Litres a water each day.
All of the leaves have sightly curled and have brown edges, as shown below:
[image: Brown fridges on leaves]

Does anybody know what this indicates?